# How to use Aeson to get a vector of strings inside a deep JSON object?

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

Let's say I want to use [Aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson) to parse the following JSON object:

```
{
    "data": [
        [ 
            "data",
            "more data"
        ],
        [ 
            "data",
            "more data"
        ]
    ],
    "error": {
        "code": ""
    }
}
```

I can create the records for the JSON objects, then create the instances to parse the pieces out like the documentation describes. But, I'm really only interested in the `Vector Text` that's inside `data`. Is there a more direct way to get at this than creating the records? It's not obvious how to create the `Parser` that gets me this directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that there is an Aeson tutorial documenting exactly this problem: [Parsing without creating extra types](https://artyom.me/aeson#parsing-without-creating-extra-types)

In your case, `data` has arrays of arrays, so I'm not sure if you want a `Vector (Vector Text)` or flatten all of it into one array, but adapting from the documentation:

```
justData :: Value -> Parser (Vector (Vector Text))
justData = withObject "structure with data" $ \o -> o .: "data"

justDataFlat :: Value -> Parser (Vector Text)
justDataFlat value = fmap join (justData value)
```

Also note that if your structure is deeper, like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "deep": [
            "data",
            "more data"
        ]
    }
}
```

you can use `.:` more than once:

```
deeperData :: Value -> Parser (Vector Text)
deeperData = withObject "structure with deeper data" $ \o ->
    step1 <- o .: "data"
    step1 .: "deep"
```

Comment: Thanks. But, to be sure, that isn't in the Aeson documentation. It is in a separate Aeson tutorial. I did not find this before posting the question.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was - found it by searching for "aeson".